# Custom UIImagePickerViewController view hides StatusBar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar

I know that a lot of people have asked this, but I am having a hard time with showing the status bar when I call the `UIImagePickerViewController`. I implemented it in my app as a "custom" control, without the standard picker controls, but when I call the view, and place it as a `subview`, the status bar disappears. I have tried with that code but it doesn't work.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:NO
                 withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

I placed it when calling the `UIImagePickerViewController`, and tried when the view appears, but nothing. Any idea?

Comment: try it presenting `Modally`. This might not be the answer but may solve your issue :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I need it in the navigationController hierarchy. I checked all the previous answers to that question, but it just doesn't affect any of those.

Comment: try putting it in your `AppDelegate` class and debug accordingly.

Comment: You mean the UIImagePickerViewController control, and then just call it from AppDelegate as it is from that view ?

Comment: No, I mean set it in `AppDelegate` once and no other place.

Comment: I have already tried with that but it doesn't work. Any other idea how to force the status bar to preview?

Comment: My Friend, I agree with you. The code should work. 1. Try clean build / restart xcode. 2. Create a new test app and check the functionality. Sometimes this works. Logic Unknown...
Or maybe there is something in the pList thats messing, though it should not. :)